# How to delete object from window javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to delete one object in my case. so i am using "delete" keyword but after using it, I am able get the value again

```
var test= {};
test[0]="111";
test[1]="555";
delete test;
alert(test[0])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't `delete` a local variable that has been declared with `var`.

You can only delete properties of objects - this happens to also include global variables which are implicit properties of the `window` object.

Answer (score 6):

As has been mentioned, you can't delete a variable that has been declared with `var`.

For example, if you were to change your code to the following - so that `test` is an explicit property of `window` - the delete will work.

```
window.test = [];
window.test[0]="111";
window.test[1]="555";
delete window.test;
alert(window.test[0]);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can `delete` properties on objects, you can't `delete` variables.

Either assign `undefined` or let the variable fall out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever `delete`, it returns a boolean that tells wether it could delete the var or not. In this case, it returns `false`:

```
delete test;    // false
```

You can just set `test` to `undefined`:

```
test = undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `test = undefined` to make remove object value